# How can I enable colored output for OSX diff?

Tags: macos, terminal, git, diff

I need to diff two files (not two versions of the same file, they are however tracked by git, but that is unrelated) and I would like some colored output, how can I achieve that?

```
$ diff file_1 file_2

1,9d0
< <script ... >
<     // more code
< </script>

$
```

Above code shows me the difference between those files, however without any colors. For longer diffs that is hard to read.

---

Alternatively, is there a way for git (with which I do have nice color output) to diff two *different* files (not changes to a file)?

`OSX (10.7.5)`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Perl has a a lackluster [colordiff](http://www.colordiff.org/) wrapper for diff, but I prefer [grc (generic colorizer)](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html).

With [grc (generic colorizer)](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html), you can write your own wrappers for different types of commands or inputs (if you like that sort of thing).

Below, `grc` is running against `/var/log/syslog` (in the config, this file is set to a certain color scheme), where it highlights processes, pids, IPs and "connect"s.

Of course, it is recommended to use an alias so you don't forget:

```
alias diff="/usr/bin/grc /usr/bin/diff"
```

[image: grc running against syslog]

---

If you have git, you may just want to use that, which allows very robust `diff`ing, even across branches.

```
git diff master:cogs/foo.txt branch:widgets/bar.txt
```

You do not have to use `git diff` within a repository, you can use it for just regular files.[image]

```
git diff old.txt new.txt
```

As always, you can alias `diff` for ease of use.

```
alias diff="git diff"
```

Comment: yay for git diff

Comment: ``git diff`` should be at the top of your answer! +1 for pointing out that it works even outside of a repository.

Comment: 'git diff' does not work on generic files so aliasing diff to be 'git diff' can be harmful

Comment: This doesn't work for me... `echo one > foo; echo two > bar; git diff foo bar` produces no output, while `diff foo bar` produces
`1c1
< one
---
> two
` (with proper formatting, of course)

Comment: `git diff` doesn't work for e.g. pipes

Comment: `git diff` does not work if both files happen to be in the same repository and currently checked-out.

Comment: `git diff` also has different command-line flags and different behavior, e.g. `git diff <dir1> <dir2>` diffs two directories recursively, while `diff <dir1> <dir2>` is not recursive and requires the `-r` flag (which `git diff` doesn't have) for a recursive diff. I'm not convinced aliasing is such a hot idea.

Comment: `git diff old.txt new.txt` did the trick. Incredible tool. Thanks

Answer (score 60):

When diffing files I almost always use vim:

```
vim -d file_1 file_2
```

It not only uses colours, it lines up the files so it's easier to see lines added/removed.

Comment: Wow... Vim is a beautiful thing.

Comment: @WestonGanger vim is indeed amazing, never ceases to impress me

Comment: vim works on git patch files too (shows colored diff)!

Comment: Best solution. Vim allows you to change and compare in real time. Very nice!

Comment: you just need to remember the arcane magic required to quit it after you're done.

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich Or just hit Ctrl-C and Vim will remind you :)

Answer (score 12):

To build on the approved answer: **grc** works great for this. It is installable with brew and colorizes a number of terminal commands out of the box, diff being one of them. So...

```
brew install grc
```

...installs grc to your system. Then you need to set up your aliases, the brew caveat provides a solution. Simply add the following line to your `.bashrc` or similar.

```
source "`brew --prefix`/etc/grc.bashrc"
```

This will currently add the following aliases:

```
alias colourify="$GRC -es --colour=auto"
alias configure='colourify ./configure'
alias diff='colourify diff'
alias make='colourify make'
alias gcc='colourify gcc'
alias g++='colourify g++'
alias as='colourify as'
alias gas='colourify gas'
alias ld='colourify ld'
alias netstat='colourify netstat'
alias ping='colourify ping'
alias traceroute='colourify /usr/sbin/traceroute'
alias head='colourify head'
alias tail='colourify tail'
alias dig='colourify dig'
alias mount='colourify mount'
alias ps='colourify ps'
alias mtr='colourify mtr'
alias df='colourify df'
```

Answer (score 10):

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) has a [formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/diffutils) for [GNU diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/), including a `diff` command with support for color.

```sh
$ brew install diffutils
```

```sh
$ /usr/local/bin/diff --color -r -c foo bar
```

[image: color output]

Comment: This is the best answer, actually - simply replaces the crippled MacOS version with the proper GNU equivalent, and magically, things work as they're supposed to be.

Comment: I also like this answer the best. But confess a fondness for the `vim -d` option, previously unknown to me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: `diffutils`!  I don't know if others will encounter this, but `brew` installed the diff utility here on my machine: `/opt/homebrew/bin/diff`.

Answer (score 9):

You can get git to [diff two different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131135/git-how-to-diff-two-different-files-in-different-branches):

```
git diff branch1:full/path/to/foo.txt branch2:full/path/to/foo-another.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio Code (VS Code) installed and on your PATH, you can run `code --diff file1 file2`.

It provides a really nice side by side comparison with word diff, syntax highlighting, editing code while running the diffs, etc.

VS Code has an option to add itself to your PATH (uses a symlink actually) that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

```sh
alias diff="git diff --no-index"
diff file_1 file_2
```

Comment: You are not using a feature of "diff", but replacing it by another tool.