# Terminal colorful output from ping?

Tags: macos, terminal, ping, colors

I just bought a new Mac and I copied my .profile settings onto the new Mac, which enabled different colors for folders and documents.

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagabeb
```

But on my old Mac output from ping used to be colorful, and I've no idea why it is colorful. I cannot replicate the same behavior on my new Mac, does anyone know what command/script will give the following colorful output for ping? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you still have your old Mac with the same install? `which` and `type` could point to a potential alias/function that wrapped ping and provided the color output.

Comment: type did the trick, after some analysis I figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own question here, it is grc, which can be installed from homebrew.

```
brew install grc
source "`brew --prefix`/etc/grc.bashrc"
```

source: https://superuser.com/a/960065/525673